# Logstash Invalid FieldReference: `[iso-8859-1]to`

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, couchdb

Some of my CouchDB records aren't being piped into Elasticsearch due to this error:

> Error: Invalid FieldReference: `[iso-8859-1]to`
> Exception: Java::OrgLogstash::FieldReference::IllegalSyntaxException
> Stack: org.logstash.FieldReference$StrictTokenizer.tokenize(FieldReference.java:303)

What does this mean and how can I determine which record caused this error?

Here's the full error log:

```
logstash         |   Pipeline_id:main
logstash         |   Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::CouchDBChanges ignore_attachments=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON id=>"json_17404f4f-4c86-4212-a2d5-caf57d2f057b", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, password=><password>, port=>5984, host=>"host.domain", sequence_path=>"0", id=>"1ddcb1db7a5cbea8408c2c27145f7f295da0f1aaea7e510fc4a182a0b5dca7c1", db=>"incidents", username=>"admin", enable_metric=>true, secure=>false, heartbeat=>1000, keep_id=>false, keep_revision=>false, always_reconnect=>true, reconnect_delay=>10>
logstash         |   Error: Invalid FieldReference: `[iso-8859-1]to`
logstash         |   Exception: Java::OrgLogstash::FieldReference::IllegalSyntaxException
logstash         |   Stack: org.logstash.FieldReference$StrictTokenizer.tokenize(FieldReference.java:303)
logstash         | org.logstash.FieldReference.parse(FieldReference.java:204)
logstash         | org.logstash.FieldReference.parseToCache(FieldReference.java:195)
logstash         | org.logstash.FieldReference.from(FieldReference.java:127)
logstash         | org.logstash.FieldReference.lambda$from$0(FieldReference.java:118)
logstash         | java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1737)
logstash         | org.logstash.FieldReference.from(FieldReference.java:118)
logstash         | org.logstash.ConvertedMap.convertKey(ConvertedMap.java:122)
logstash         | org.logstash.ConvertedMap.access$000(ConvertedMap.java:44)
logstash         | org.logstash.ConvertedMap$1.visit(ConvertedMap.java:55)
logstash         | org.logstash.ConvertedMap$1.visit(ConvertedMap.java:49)
logstash         | org.jruby.RubyHash.visitLimited(RubyHash.java:698)
logstash         | org.jruby.RubyHash.visitAll(RubyHash.java:683)
logstash         | org.logstash.ConvertedMap.newFromRubyHash(ConvertedMap.java:89)
logstash         | org.logstash.ConvertedMap.newFromRubyHash(ConvertedMap.java:84)
logstash         | org.logstash.Valuefier.lambda$initConverters$12(Valuefier.java:171)
logstash         | org.logstash.Valuefier.convert(Valuefier.java:94)
logstash         | org.logstash.ConvertedMap$1.visit(ConvertedMap.java:55)
logstash         | org.logstash.ConvertedMap$1.visit(ConvertedMap.java:49)
logstash         | org.jruby.RubyHash.visitLimited(RubyHash.java:698)
logstash         | org.jruby.RubyHash.visitAll(RubyHash.java:683)
logstash         | org.logstash.ConvertedMap.newFromRubyHash(ConvertedMap.java:89)
logstash         | org.logstash.ConvertedMap.newFromRubyHash(ConvertedMap.java:84)
logstash         | org.logstash.Valuefier.lambda$initConverters$12(Valuefier.java:171)
logstash         | org.logstash.Valuefier.convert(Valuefier.java:94)
logstash         | org.logstash.ConvertedMap$1.visit(ConvertedMap.java:55)
logstash         | org.logstash.ConvertedMap$1.visit(ConvertedMap.java:49)
logstash         | org.jruby.RubyHash.visitLimited(RubyHash.java:698)
logstash         | org.jruby.RubyHash.visitAll(RubyHash.java:683)
logstash         | org.logstash.ConvertedMap.newFromRubyHash(ConvertedMap.java:89)
logstash         | org.logstash.ext.JrubyEventExtLibrary$RubyEvent.ruby_initialize(JrubyEventExtLibrary.java:92)
logstash         | usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_couchdb_changes_minus_3_dot_1_dot_6.lib.logstash.inputs.couchdb_changes.RUBY$method$build_event$0(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-couchdb_changes-3.1.6/lib/logstash/inputs/couchdb_changes.rb:235)
logstash         | usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_couchdb_changes_minus_3_dot_1_dot_6.lib.logstash.inputs.couchdb_changes.RUBY$block$run$4(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-couchdb_changes-3.1.6/lib/logstash/inputs/couchdb_changes.rb:176)
logstash         | org.jruby.runtime.CompiledIRBlockBody.yieldDirect(CompiledIRBlockBody.java:148)
logstash         | org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.yield(BlockBody.java:106)
logstash         | org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:184)
logstash         | org.jruby.RubyArray.each(RubyArray.java:1809)
logstash         | usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_couchdb_changes_minus_3_dot_1_dot_6.lib.logstash.inputs.couchdb_changes.RUBY$block$run$3(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-couchdb_changes-3.1.6/lib/logstash/inputs/couchdb_changes.rb:167)
logstash         | uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.protocol.RUBY$method$call_block$0(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/protocol.rb:433)
logstash         | uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.protocol.RUBY$method$\=\^\^$0(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/protocol.rb:424)
logstash         | uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.protocol.RUBY$method$read$0(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/protocol.rb:129)
logstash         | uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.http.response.RUBY$method$read_chunked$0(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/http/response.rb:321)
logstash         | uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.http.response.RUBY$block$read_body_0$1(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/http/response.rb:285)
logstash         | uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.http.response.RUBY$method$inflater$0(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/http/response.rb:278)
logstash         | uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.http.response.RUBY$method$read_body_0$0(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/http/response.rb:283)
logstash         | uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.http.response.RUBY$method$read_body$0(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/http/response.rb:204)
logstash         | usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_couchdb_changes_minus_3_dot_1_dot_6.lib.logstash.inputs.couchdb_changes.RUBY$block$run$2(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-couchdb_changes-3.1.6/lib/logstash/inputs/couchdb_changes.rb:166)
logstash         | uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.http.RUBY$block$transport_request$2(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/http.rb:1513)
logstash         | uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.http.response.RUBY$method$reading_body$0(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/http/response.rb:165)
logstash         | uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.http.RUBY$method$transport_request$0(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/http.rb:1512)
logstash         | uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.http.RUBY$method$request$0(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/http.rb:1474)
logstash         | usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_couchdb_changes_minus_3_dot_1_dot_6.lib.logstash.inputs.couchdb_changes.RUBY$block$run$1(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-couchdb_changes-3.1.6/lib/logstash/inputs/couchdb_changes.rb:161)
logstash         | uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.http.RUBY$method$start$0(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/http.rb:914)
logstash         | uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.http.RUBY$method$start$0(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/http.rb:609)
logstash         | usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_couchdb_changes_minus_3_dot_1_dot_6.lib.logstash.inputs.couchdb_changes.RUBY$method$run$0(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-couchdb_changes-3.1.6/lib/logstash/inputs/couchdb_changes.rb:157)
logstash         | usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$inputworker$0(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:378)
logstash         | usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$inputworker$0$__VARARGS__(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb)
logstash         | org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80)
logstash         | org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70)
logstash         | org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)
logstash         | usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$block$start_input$1(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:369)
logstash         | org.jruby.runtime.CompiledIRBlockBody.callDirect(CompiledIRBlockBody.java:138)
logstash         | org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:58)
logstash         | org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:52)
logstash         | org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:139)
logstash         | org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:318)
logstash         | org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:105)
logstash         | java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
logstash         | [2020-09-14T19:09:15,305][INFO ][logstash.inputs.couchdbchanges][main][1ddcb1db7a5cbea8408c2c27145f7f295da0f1aaea7e510fc4a182a0b5dca7c1] Connecting to CouchDB _changes stream at: {:host=>"host.domain", :port=>"5984", :db=>"incidents"}
logstash         | [2020-09-14T19:09:15,306][INFO ][logstash.inputs.couchdbchanges][main][1ddcb1db7a5cbea8408c2c27145f7f295da0f1aaea7e510fc4a182a0b5dca7c1] Using service uri : {:uri=>#<URI::HTTP http://host.domain:5984/incidents/_changes?feed=continuous&include_docs=true&since=4586095-g1AAAAI7eJzLYWBg4MhgTmHgzcvPy09JdcjLz8gvLskBCjMlMiTJ____PyuDOYmBc3lGLlCM3cQy2SLJ3ARdPQ4TkhSAZJI93JA9P8GGmKZYGBmYEm2IA8iQeJghTCIVEJekJhkaGFsQa0gCyJB6uEvWrwMbkmpomJycSqxL8liAJEMDkAKaMx9i0GZ_sEGJKSZplmlGJBm0AGLQfohBu4zBBgG9lGpgnEySQQcgBt2HGLQ2DGKQYaqhWbIxSQY9gBgEDaPtAmCDzAxNzIwszdC1ZQEAodmvng&heartbeat=1000>}
logstash         | [2020-09-14T19:09:15,319][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ][main][1ddcb1db7a5cbea8408c2c27145f7f295da0f1aaea7e510fc4a182a0b5dca7c1] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
```